# VS Code Intellisense

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've just starting using Visual Studio Code, and I've changed quite a lot of the config. I like Intellisense, and I've become comfortable with it in PowerShell ISE.

However in VS Code it seems to always want to suggest modules or objects with the letters in the same order through the suggestion:

So for instance if I haven't used the variable `$test` in my code it will still give me the suggestions of:

- $Git**T**abS**e**tting**s**
- $**T**ortois**e**Git**S**e**t**tings
- $Gi**t**PromptS**e**tting**s**
- $curren**t**Git**S**ta**t**us
- $LogSe**t**tingsEv**e**n**t**
- $PSDefaul**t**Param**e**terValue**s**

If I have used it then it gives the same list but with $**test** as the top option.

I only want this option, I don't need or want the others, does anyone have any clue how to get rid of them?

Comment: Sounds like those are automatic/environment variables from your git / tortoise installations or something from your profile. I'm pretty sure intellisense is using the `Get-Variable` cmdlet to find available fill-ins. (considering intellisense doesn't work at all without integrated PS running, this confirms my suspicion).  Consider re-configuring the installation of your git/tortoise or launching PS with `-NoProfile`

Comment: It's more around the fact that Intellisense in the ISE only completes words which are started correctly, where VS Code seems to make suggestions where the letters are interspersed in order through the command / variable which is what I don't want it to do.